# Why doesn't my dishwasher work after doing work in the electric panel?

Tags: electrical, appliances

My Whirlpool dish washwer recently stopped working. It's been used about 2 years. The buttons still SEEM to work because they light up and make the beep-y noises as you push them. But when I hit "start", nothing happens. This happens to coincide with some work that was done in our electric panel, which is quite the coincidence...

For troubleshooting, I have unplugged the unit and confirmed that it doesn't work on a different circuit, and the same outlet worked for another electric device. I've also flipped the breaker off for an hour and then flipped it back. I've held down the start and stop buttons (hoping that cleared something). None of that had any effect.

So one theory is that the work in the electric panel damaged something in the machine. Anyone have any tips/advice/thoughts?

Comment: Could have fried the board in the dishwasher, esp a capacitor or a relay.  Probably time to bring in a tech.

Comment: Was this _your_ work in the panel or did you hire it out? If you hired an electrician and can _reliably_ tie the failure to the work date/time, a good business owner might be willing to pay for repairs or at least split costs. At a minimum, he might send someone out to review the work they did to see if there were any errors at their end.

Comment: While it might be possible that work in the panel(which I hope was done with power off), might cause a problem, I think it is just unlucky timing.

Comment: This was my work in the panel (@FreeMan ), and I forgot to flip the breaker off before moving a few of the neutrals around (repositioning them to make space for an added circuit). Kicking myself ...

Comment: Seems like that might be vital info to [edit] into your question.

Comment: Before going down the rabbit hole of diagnosing and replacing the mother board or dishwasher, take a deep breath and go back to basics.   Find the manual for your dishwasher, and go through basic diagnostic steps.  Maybe you engaged the delay timer?  Maybe the door isn't closing properly?   Those are two random guesses made without the benefit of your manual.  Use the manual, use Google, and use YouTube to find people with your problem and how they handled it.   Similarly,try the Customer Service number for Whirlpool, they may walk you through some tests.

Answer (score 2):

Since it seems that you removed the neutral from this circuit and reconnected it *without* turning the breaker off, I'd speculate that there were probably actually *multiple* disconnects/reconnects as the neutral wire was wiggled around. The multiple power surges may well have fried some circuitry, but not all.

My tips/advice/thoughts:

1. Don't **EVER** work on a circuit without turning the breaker off!
2. Investigate the cost of replacement control board(s) for the dishwasher and weigh that up against the cost of a replacement washer.

   1. Don't forget to factor in the hassle of possibly having to replace more than one board after discovering that the previous one replaced may not fix it.
3. Learn your lesson and don't work on wiring again *without turning off the breaker first*.

Comment: Is there anything that I can do/test with limited appliance equipment?

Comment: Probably not, in this case, if you have to ask.